# Restricting comment feature on Facebook Page to Users who liked the page?

Tags: facebook, comments

Anyone aware of a way to restrict the capability of users to comment on a wall post on a Facebook Page to those who have liked that particular Facebook page?

Or is the user-linked-page information really only useable and accesible in an Facebook App Tab page?

Comment: That sounds a bit like coercion to me.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, this will not be bullet proof, because anyone can comment a page even if the FB comment widget is not installed.

Try to fill the form on this page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
with for instance www.google.com as URL.

You will be able to see comments has been made, (and you can add one) but I promise : Facebook has not installed any Facebook widget on google.com ;-)

Regards

Antoine